# Could not find configuration node: marketingDefinitions/funnel/funnelStepTypeResolver

Tags: solr, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Sitecore 8.1 update 4 to Sitecore 8.2 update 2. I am on Solr 6.1 and while doing the upgrade we are getting the below error:

```
Could not find configuration node: marketingDefinitions/funnel/funnelStepTypeResolver

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find 
configuration node: marketingDefinitions/funnel/funnelStepTypeResolver

Source Error: 

windsorSolrStartUp.AddCore(suggestionsIndex.SwapIndexName, typeof(SuggestionsIndexMapper), ConfigurationSettings.ContentSearch_Solr_ServiceBaseAddress + "/" + suggestionsIndex.SwapIndexName);


windsorSolrStartUp.Initialize();
    }
```

All the Dll's are updated to the new ones and also the references are updated.

Can someone please help me with this..Thank You.

Comment: Do you have the `Sitecore.Marketing.config` in the include folder? If yes, make sure that it is not disabled

Comment: Thank you so much.. That worked. We had that file but it was missing the latest changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue being raised is because it cannot find the XPath `marketingDefinitions/funnel/funnelStepTypeResolver`.

Make sure that you have the `Sitecore.Marketing.config` in the include folder. If the file is present, you need to see if the config file is not disabled.

While performing Sitecore upgrades, normally, the changes to config files are not done properly. So, make sure that you have the XPath `marketingDefinitions/funnel/funnelStepTypeResolver` in the file.

Comment: But what is trying to find that XPath in `Sitecore.Marketing.config`? I think that's my error; it should not be trying to find that there.